# Activestate install module

Tags: windows, perl, activestate

I just installed ActiveState to test the alternative to Cygwin/Perl and I get some problems to install a cpan package.

I would like to install `Win32::GuiTest` which is not listed under ppm. I then started a cmd.exe and typed:

`C:\>cpan Win32::GuiTest`

which returns:

```
c:\>cpan Win32::GuiTest
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.45)
Reading '\cygdrive\e\home\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 22 Sep 2014 15:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Win32::GuiTest'
Running make for K/KA/KARASIK/Win32-GuiTest-1.60.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.85)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.063)
Checksum for \cygdrive\e\home\.cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KA\KARASIK\Win32-GuiTest-1.60.tar.gz ok
The system cannot find the path specified.
Uncompressed \cygdrive\e\home\.cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KA\KARASIK\Win32-GuiTest-1.60.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/usr/bin/tar xf "Win32-GuiTest-1.60.tar":
The system cannot find the path specified.
Couldn't untar Win32-GuiTest-1.60.tar: child exited with value 1
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.132830)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9726)
Package seems to come without Makefile.PL.
  (The test -f "\cygdrive\e\home\.cpan\build\KARASIK-85id4t\Makefile.PL" returned false.)
  Writing one on our own (setting NAME to Win32GuiTest)
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

So it seems `cpan` interacts somehow with cygwin and I don't know why. And I am running the correct version of cpan:

```
c:\>cpan --help
C:\Perl64\bin/cpan.bat version 1.61 calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.07 [paranoid]),
running under Perl version 5.18.2.

Usage: cpan.bat [-OPTIONS [-MORE_OPTIONS]] [--] [PROGRAM_ARG1 ...]

The following single-character options are accepted:
        With arguments: -j
        Boolean (without arguments): -h -v -V -I -g -G -C -A -D -O -l -L -a -r -p -P -J -w -T -c -f -i -m -t -u

Options may be merged together.  -- stops processing of options.
Space is not required between options and their arguments.

For more details run
        perldoc -F C:\Perl64\bin/cpan.bat
  [Now continuing due to backward compatibility and excessive paranoia.
   See 'perldoc Getopt::Std' about $Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION.]
Nothing to install!
```

Does someone knows what I did wrong?

Comment: Try it through the ppm gui? It should be installed on your computer somewhere you can get to through the start menu or run ppm on the command line http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_gui

Comment: Only opinion: as alternative to cygwin try DWIM-perl, it installs Strawberry perl, mingw compiler and many modules, also Padre.